# Was the new-user image restrictions revoked?

Tags: support, editing

I just encountered this question: [Node reference field share between two content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/96061/16495)

User with rep 1, two questions, and he posts images. I'm sure it wasn't possible when I started. Was it changed? Cant find a post about that on MSO, so maybe it changed only on some sites in the network?

Comment: What do you mean 2 questions, he posted only one

Comment: @Bala I have seen two when I last checked. Or I'm imagining it? It takes a moderator to tell now. Maybe the other one was deleted, maybe I'm mistaken, can't really tell now.

Comment: AFAIK 1 rep user can post any number of questions.

Comment: But I'm talking about **images** in questions. There was a restriction to prevent newcomers from posting erection pills spam with illustrations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Molot yaa the restriction is removed except Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User.

For more info check here [New users and attaching images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111388/new-users-and-attaching-images)

> We examined this issue and decided that on most sites, the restriction
>   is doing more harm than good. The restriction has therefore simply
>   been removed on all sites except Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask
>   Ubuntu and Super User.